# align two image at left and right of RelativeLayout with central element matching the whole free space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm workin on an Android app (comptabile with android 2.3 and higher) and I need to make a coverflow with two navigations arrows aligned at left and right of the coverflow

I tried many things, but can't figure out to make the left arrow aligned at the left of the layout and the right arrow at the right of the layout.

I always have margins even if I havent specified padding or margin

Here is a screenshot : http://accessdev.s3.amazonaws.com/temp/layout_madness_android.jpg

I used a black background in order to show that the size is correct (100% of parent) but we can see that the arrows are not left/right aligned.

I checked and the problem is not inside the images itselves.

here is my layout code, help would be appreciated :)

```
  <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/BonsPlans_coverFlowAndArrows"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="145px"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:background="#ff000000"
            android:paddingLeft="0px"
            android:paddingRight="0px"
             >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bonsplans_fleche_gauche"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
                android:paddingLeft="0px"
                android:paddingRight="0px"
                android:src="@drawable/fleche_gauche" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bonsplans_fleche_droite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
                android:paddingLeft="0px"
                android:paddingRight="0px"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@drawable/fleche_gauche"
                android:src="@drawable/fleche_droite" />

            <pl.polidea.coverflow.CoverFlow
                xmlns:coverflow="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.accessdev.tellmeplus"
                android:id="@+id/BonsPlans_coverflow"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="145px"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bonsplans_fleche_droite"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bonsplans_fleche_gauche"
                coverflow:imageHeight="125px"
                coverflow:imageWidth="150px" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_toRightOf="@drawable/fleche_gauche"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use LinearLayout. Set fixed widths for left and right image  e.g.

```
android:layout_width="30dp"
```

And for center one (it will resize itself)

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following lines:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@drawable/fleche_gauche"
```

from your **bonsplans_fleche_droite** view

And from the center view:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bonsplans_fleche_droite"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bonsplans_fleche_gauche"
```